# ag-grid custom date component with ngx-boostrap

Tags: angular, datepicker, ag-grid, ngx-bootstrap

I want to create my custom date filter with a nice datepicker. I added a custom date component as described here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-date-component

In this component I use ngx-bootstrap's BsDatepickerModule. The datepicker is showing and working.

The problem is, after selecting a date not  just the datepicker is closed, the whole filter menu is closing. I want the user to press the apply filter first. This is especially troublesome for date ranges where the user has to enter two dates.

See the following plunker for demo:
https://plnkr.co/edit/hM7uAZaadbjoGcXPRaDP

How can the filter menu be prevented from closing after selecting a date via BsDatepickerModule datepicker?

customDate.component.html

```
<div class="filter">
    <input type="text"
    #dp="bsDatepicker"
    bsDatepicker
    [bsValue]="date"
    [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY' }">
</div>
```

customDate.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-customdatecomponent",
  templateUrl: "./customDate.component.html",
})
export class CustomDateComponent  {
  private date: Date;
  private params: any;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
  }
  onResetDate() {
    this.setDate(null);
    this.params.onDateChanged();
  }
  onDateChanged(event) {
    this.params.onDateChanged();
  }
  getDate(): Date {
    return this.date;
  }
  setDate(date: Date): void {
    this.date = date;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I am having the exact same problem. The one provided answer doesn't really answer the problem.

Comment: I didn't solve it, I used ng-pick-datetime with the "dialog" option. This kinda worked but wasn't perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 04/26/2023**: On later version of ag-grid (I am on ag-grid v25), this process has been simplified significantly. Per the documentation [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-filter/#custom-filters-containing-a-popup-element),

- Add the `ag-custom-component-popup` CSS class to your floating element.

For the given example of bsDatepicker, we can just do the following...

```
<div class="filter">
   <input type="text"
       #dp="bsDatepicker"
       bsDatepicker
       [bsValue]="date"
       [bsConfig]="{dateInputFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY', containerClass: 'ag-custom-component-popup'}">
</div>
```

**(Original response below)**

Since I wasn't able to find any other solutions to this problem on SO, I want to provide my solution to this problem.

What's happening is that when you click the datepicker popup, its creating the element outside of the context of ag-grid's pop-up service. Since the datepicker element is not within the pop-up service's current context, clicking the datepicker means ag-grid thinks you clicked outside of the filter and that you want to close the filter pop-up.

To solve the problem, you want to add an event handler for `onShown` to the datepicker to add the component to ag-grid's pop-up service.

customDate.component.html

```html
<div class="filter">
    <input type="text"
           #dp="bsDatepicker"
           bsDatepicker
           [bsValue]="date"
           (onShown)="addDatepickerToAgGridContext($event)"
           [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY' }">
</div>
```

Then, in the event handler, you simply navigate to the popupService in the API that is available to you in your `params` and add the datepicker to the list of active elements. In our case, the datepicker is instantiated in a tag `bs-datepicker-container`, so you want to use JS to select that element, then add it to the array.

```js
addDatepickerToAgGridContext(e){
    this.params.api.gridCore.popupService.activePopupElements.push(document.getElementsByTagName("bs-datepicker-container")[0]);
}
```

Note on later versions of ag-grid (I'm now on `"ag-grid-community": "22.0.0"`), the path to the list of active popup elements has **changed**. The active popup elements is now stored in the array at `api.gridCore.popupService.popupList`.

```js
addDatepickerToAgGridContext(e){
    this.params.api.gridCore.popupService.popupList.push(
       {element: document.getElementsByTagName("bs-datepicker-container")[0]}
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I applied it for ng-pick-datetime and it works too.

Comment: Thanks again for the edit for version > 22, works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

For `"ag-grid-community": "25.0.0"` you can resolve the problem adding **filterParams** inside "params":

```
addDatepickerToAgGridContext(e) {
    this.params.filterParams.api.gridCore.popupService.popupList.push(
      { element: document.getElementsByTagName("bs-datepicker-container")[0] }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to develop a custom component that incorporates BS date picker in a popover with Apply button. In one of my project, we had a custom datepicker component to use in ag-grid that incorporated ng-bootstrap date picker on a popover (no apply button) with a few customization options. However, it was a non-trivial effort and the component took sometime to become production ready.

Answer (score 0):

For `"ag-grid-community": "25.3.0"`

```js
addDatepickerToAgGridContext(e){
    // @ts-ignore
    this.params.api.gridCompController.popupService.popupList.push(
       {element: document.getElementsByTagName("bs-datepicker-container")[0]}
    );
}
```